# Apache2 + Disable Default Virtual Server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization

This is the first time I actually try to setup a server myself.

Everything is working good so far. I have added a new virtual server and changed my domain´s A records and it is now working as expected.

However: I would like to "block" access to the default www dir (in my case `var/www`). Right now when I enter the server IP instead of the domain, I get to the default www dir - I would like to disable that.

I dont want to setup a redirect, but simply forbid users, search engines etc. to view anything when they go to `http://myip/`

Currently I am doing the trick with adding an empty `index.html`, but I would like to actually block all requests and only allow access to my domains (they are in a subdir like "`var/www/sites/domain.com/www`")

I hope you get what I mean - my english sucks :/

p.s. since I installed webmin and I access it through `http://myIp:webminPort` - I think I actually only want to block port 80, but not sure about that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep port 80 open as all your content for the domain.com/www vhost travels through 80 as well.

There is a default vhost setup by apache, you just need to comment it out in your httpd.conf.

To edit the config in webmin:

```
 Webmin -> Servers -> Apache Website -> Global Configuration
```

Give it a slow read through and you'll find the default vhost code block, just comment it out. This is worth it as you may want to tune settings later anyways.

**Andre(OP) determined the default vhost definition was in /sites-enabled/default-000**

Here is the section you are looking for:

```
### Section 2: 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#
```

Comment out these Directives within Section 2 using a hash:

```
#ServerName
#<Directory />
#<Directory>
#---comment out all contents of this directory block---
#<Directory /var/www/html>
#---comment out all contents of this directory block---
#</Directory>
#DocumentRoot
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything regarding the default vserver, but I did the following: I opened the config file in `apache2/sites-enabled` and added `<Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Order allow,deny
Deny from all AllowOverride None </Directory>` - this works good now as I get a `403` error when accessing my ip via port 80, but can still access via webmin port. Just wondering: was that a bad idea or its fine?

Comment: 404 Would be better. 403 indicates "forbidden". You are close you just need to comment out a couple more things to get the server to stop responding on that IP on 80. Is the file you edited the "default site" in sites-enabled/? If there is no webmin configuration in there you can safely remove it from sites-enabled/

Comment: Thanks again for the tip, but it seems [my config file](http://pastebin.com/EKdTsQgA) doesnt include this parts.

Comment: Ah, that must be a webmin thing. You are on the right track. Its likely all in the default-site vhost

Comment: yes it is named `000-default` in `sites-enabled/` and there is no webmin config, but some config regarding port 443 (ssl i guess). I am gonna save it, delete it and restore it in case something breaks

Comment: it should be saved in sites-available/ to re-add/enable it you just re-create the symlink of the original file into sites-enabled/. You basically store all of your configs in sites-available and enable them using symlinks to sites-enabled (ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/). Let me know how it goes!

Comment: thanks for all your help. I now removed `DocumentRoot /var/www/` within the `000-default`, and I am now getting a `404` instead of `403` - do you think thats good now or did I forget about something?